# How to reinstall Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, system-installation, usb-installation

I don't have windows to do the same installation of ubuntu 20.04 and i can't login to my Ubuntu.

[image: This what i see when i open my computer.]

Comment: You _have_ to have another working computer to download the Ubuntu ISO file and burn it onto a DVD or copy it to an USB drive. Step by step instructions are given here: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop You can ask a friend to use their computer for the first steps.

Comment: What were you doing before this error message appeared? 

Answer (score 0):

Do you still have the USB-stick/SD-card/DVD you used to install Ubuntu? If yes use that. If no you need another computer ( friend, public library, locutorio/parlor ) to make one.